# Wordpress layout and font changes between www.example.com/blog and example.com/blog

Tags: wordpress, fonts, layout, no-www

A WordPress installation using `http://www.example.com/blog` shows a wrong font (and due to that a wrong layout) whereas using `http://example.com/blog` shows the correct font and layout.

This happens on Firefox and IE9. Chrome and IE8 do not behave like this.

I'm at a total loss about the possible causes for this, could you enlighten me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Updated based on the comment provided by @Lèsemajesté*

This happens because FF and IE9 have chosen to implement an anti-cross-domain DRM mechanism for web fonts.

I fixed it by using the following code in my htaccess file to pin the site to a single domain no matter which version of a url it's accessed from (this also seemed useful from an SEO point of view).

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.org.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.org.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

You can also workaround the problem by [embedding the font in your style sheet using base64 encoding](http://geoff.evason.name/2010/05/03/cross-domain-workaround-for-font-face-and-firefox/).

Comment: Yes, it is indeed an embedded font. I thought about pinning the site to a domain, but wanted to know if there's an alternative.

Comment: @VinkoVrsalovic not so far as I can tell.

Comment: That's because IE and FF have chosen to implement an anti-cross-domain DRM mechanism for web fonts (no doubt to appease the type foundries). [Another workaround is by embedding the fonts in your stylesheet themselves using base64 encoding](http://geoff.evason.name/2010/05/03/cross-domain-workaround-for-font-face-and-firefox/).

Comment: @Lèsemajesté I guessed that must be the reason, interesting that base64 gets around it.

Comment: @VinkoVrsalovic answer updated to reflect Lese's comment which adds an alternative to my work around and clearer reasoning.

Comment: Great news @Lèsemajesté. Although I find the DRM protection within subdomains to be a bit ridiculous and over the top.